# Reputation not showing up in the achievements tab anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

As you can clearly see from the below screenshot, the top bar and the reputation tab are showing different stats. Is it a known issue or we're seeing some bug here?

- **OS:** Windows 7
- **Browser:** Chrome 43+
- **Status (At the time of posting this question):** Difference is noticed for more than 5 mins, even after several refresh.

[image]

Comment: Same here, been so for an hour or so

Comment: Do you want to move your question to MSE since the issue is network wide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was an issue with our new Colorado web tier grabbing aggregation duties from the background queues which process this. The error in site setting precedence has been corrected and the queue is now draining at about 1,000 items a second. It should finish flushing in a few minutes then return to near-real-time.

Comment: Lol, be careful not to ddos yourself again :D

Comment: Only understood _"There was an issue.."_ and _"...should finish flushing in a few minutes then return to near-real-time"_ part which is actually enough for me as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be fixed at my end now. I received the reputation for an accepted answer. The day score on MSE is still off in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have accepted @NickCraver 's answer as it provides the related details. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Of course. I was just reflecting my own experience.