# Reputation and Achievements not in sync regarding daily reputation gain

Tags: bug

Today I noticed that the `Achievements` and the `Reputation` tab are out of sync with each other, as can be seen from my screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]
deletion happened at least an hour or more ago I don't think it has to do with lag in communication between the two. So is there a reason `Achievements` 
The reason most likely is that I had an edit on a post that was later removed due to too many downvotes, therefore undoing my `+2 Reputation` for an approved edit. However the Achievements tab does not take this into account. As the doesn't take this into account, am I just too impatient, or is this a bug?

Edit: I also found this question: [Reputation not showing up in the achievements tab anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297483/reputation-not-showing-up-in-the-achievements-tab-anymore) but there was a reasonable explanation there, that I don't think is still at play here.

Edit 2: I just gained another +2 Reputation, but the difference of two points between `Achievements` and `Reputation` still remains.

Comment: Anyone that has any ideas about this? It still occurs....