# Recent achievement reputation not showing updated score in dropdown

Tags: bug, reputation

I noticed this morning that my recent achievement reputation is not showing my updated score from the "recent achievement reputation" dropdown.

I received many notifications from the icon as a `+1`, or `+5`, etc. and from quite a few times, but they're not showing up in the dropdown.

Is this a bug?

I don't think this is a cache issue, since the same behaviour is happening on different browsers and different machines I have.

I also asked another member if he was experiencing the same problem, but said he did not.

This is rather strange, and again seeing this is happening to me only, unless others are also experiencing the same thing.

I did find a few already-asked questions, but nothing recent.

One being and dated back to June 2015:

- [Reputation not showing up in the achievements tab anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297483/reputation-not-showing-up-in-the-achievements-tab-anymore)

I have provided a screencap.

[image]

Comment: MSE dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295006/are-the-reputation-notifications-broken-again

Comment: @NathanOliver ah thanks. Ok, that explains it. It's in a different area.

Comment: No problem.  I reported to Oded [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346191/is-the-rep-widget-broken-again) thinking the same problem happened again but that turns out not to be the case.

Comment: @NathanOliver However, the answer states *"All should be well in under 5 minutes"* - This has happened to me about an hour ago and their answer was posted 30 mins after. - Maybe it just needs to propagate to my account maybe?

Comment: I did not get a notification for the rep I missed but clicking on the drop down now does show the correct rep.  Is the entry still missing for you in the drop down?

Comment: What are you not seeing that you are expecting to see? As far as I know, the problem we have had earlier has been fixed - the queue has cleared.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Looking at [your rep page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii?tab=reputation) you have not gained any rep today or yesterday.

Comment: @NathanOliver Funny; I distinctively remember seeing a +5 notification earlier and the retracted downvote from a deleted question did not appear in the notification. This is getting too weird.

Comment: Could be the person retracted their vote.  From everything I can see the drop down should not have any rep notifications in it except for you down voting something if you did.

Comment: @NathanOliver *"Could be the person retracted their vote."* - You could be right; I guess I can't leave that out of the equation. It could most likely have something to do with also but wouldn't that "possible retracted" vote not show up anywhere, even within my own rep tab?

Comment: Not sure.  I can't remember how retracted votes show up in the rep tab.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have seen retracted rep from unaccepted answers before, that to me should also apply to retracted (up)votes on a question that they might have upvoted on, since those (5's) are related to question rep upvotes.

Comment: at this moment I have the same problem, i will wait how much time ?