# Missing badges in achievements dropdown

Tags: support, badges, achievements-dialog

Today I just realized that I got 3 badges this week (*Caucus*, *Scholar* & *Quorum* [ this one 2h ago]) but just one is show in the achievements dropdown menu.

I already notice that sometimes it may take a while to update, but not more than a day.

I already found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348239/recent-achievement-reputation-not-showing-updated-score-in-dropdown), however it is from last year, and the problem seems to be solved.
Also, my achievement bar is the same, does not matter with Stack Exchange website I'm in.

Anyone else with similar problems?

*My achievements menu:*

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138113/295232), Scholar and Quorum are not shown in the achievements inbox if you're a 'veteran' user. They're simply deemed not noteworthy enough. The threshold for this is 200 reputation, which you have.